# how to swap images using Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to build 15-puzzle game.

Here I need to swap a blank image with a clicked on image. I would like to know how to swap these images.

I have stored the co-ordinates of the two images,but don't know the format to identify the blank image and then set its origin to clicked image.

Comment: If you'd like help with your question, it would be a good idea to accept answers to your other questions.

Comment: You should probably also identify whether this is for the desktop or iPhone.

Comment: I have used the following code to swap the blank image to clicked image:
   UIImageView *picture = [[UIImageView alloc]     initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"]];
  picture.center = CGPointMake(blankx,blanky);
  [picture release];

where "16.png" is blank image and (blankx,blanky) is the (x,y) co-ordinate of clicked image.but unfortunetly black image doesn't move.
plz someone help me.

Comment: russell: All you're doing is creating one view and not putting it in the view hierarchy. Working with only one view does not count as a swap, and not putting it in the view hierarchy is guaranteed to not draw anything. You need to re-read the documentation on views in UIKit.

Comment: To Peter Hosey:
 CGRect dragRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 64.0f, 64.0f);
  dragRect.origin = CGPointMake(a,b);
  DragView *dragger = [[DragView alloc]        initWithFrame:dragRect];
NSString whichflower=@"1.png";
[dragger setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:whichFlower]];
  [dragger setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  [self.view addSubview:dragger];
  [dragger release];
 
  this works well when I used it inside - (void)loadView .but when I do this in  - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
  the following line 
[self.view addSubview:dragger];
show error.so what can i do?

Answer (score 2):

Present each tile as a CALayer. To swap two tiles, set each layer's position to the other's position.